# Lightroom 5: Displaying a stack in Survey View

Tags: lightroom

I'm using Lightroom 5, and was wondering if there's a quick way to display all items in a stack in Survey View.

Right now, I can do that by:

1. Expanding the stack
2. Selecting all items in the stack
3. Switching to survey view

I was wondering if there was a quick way to click on the stack and get it to open in Survey View.

Failing *that* I was wondering if I could automatically select all the items in a stack.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I select the collapsed stack while pressing the `shift key`, in this way I have selected all photos in the stack, then I can click on `survey view` or just press `N` key

Comment: Yep, that did the trick!  It turns out double clicking the number-of-items-in-the-stack badge works too :)